# Docker network, No targets have presented acceptable certificates

Tags: corda

I moved from runnodes to docker-compose with party[a/b] and notary node. One use case which was working with runnodes does not work anymore, obviously it must be related to the new network setup. I tried to download the tools but most download links don't work. Can anyone give me a hint please what I can do? A rest-server calls party-a via rpc, it throws an error though after a while like this:

```
api-gateway    | D 17:47:23 71 RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler - Got message from RPC server Observation(id=99f3bc35-10ec-4b0f-8fa2-15156fec43e4, timestamp: 2019-06-25T17:47:15.587Z, entityType: Invocation, content=[rx.Notification@66fc17ad OnNext [(0, Starting), (0, Generating transaction.), (0, Verifying contract constraints.), (0, Signing transaction with our private key.), (1, Collecting signatures from counterparties.), (1, Verifying collected signatures.), (0, Gathering the counterparty's signature.), (1, Collecting signatures from counterparties.), (1, Verifying collected signatures.), (0, Obtaining notary signature and recording transaction.), (1, Requesting signature by notary service), (2, Requesting signature by Notary service), (2, Validating response from Notary service), (1, Broadcasting transaction to participants), (0, Done)]], deduplicationIdentity=fb9d4547-bd57-4b50-81e0-a6a01077b4a2)
party-a        | [ERROR] 17:47:25+0000 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPChannelHandler.invoke - Provided certificate subject O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB not in expected set [O=Notary, L=London, C=GB] {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=Notary, L=London, C=GB, localCert=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, remoteAddress=localhost/127.0.0.1:10002, remoteCert=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, serverMode=false}
party-a        | [ERROR] 17:47:25+0000 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient.invoke - Blocking future connection attempts to localhost:10002 due to bad certificate on endpoint
party-a        | [ERROR] 17:47:26+0000 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPClient.nextTarget - No targets have presented acceptable certificates for [O=Notary, L=London, C=GB]. Halting retries
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  notary:
    depends_on:
      - "party-a"
    container_name: notary
    image: notary
    build: build/nodes/Notary
  party-a:
    container_name: party-a
    image: party-a
    build: build/nodes/PartyA
  party-b:
    depends_on:
      - "party-a"
    container_name: party-b
    image: party-b
    build: build/nodes/PartyB
  api-gateway:
    depends_on:
      - "notary"
    container_name: api-gateway
    image: api-gateway
    build: server/
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Deploy nodes:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Dockerform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    nodeDefaults {
        cordapp project(':contracts')
        cordapp project(':workflows')
    }
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
        rpcUsers = rpcUsersList
        notary = [validating: false]
        useTestClock true
        p2pAddress "localhost:10002"
        rpcSettings {
            address("0.0.0.0:10003")
            adminAddress("0.0.0.0:10004")
        }
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        rpcUsers = [[user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
        useTestClock true
        p2pAddress "localhost:10002"
        rpcSettings {
            address("0.0.0.0:10003")
            adminAddress("0.0.0.0:10004")
        }
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
        rpcUsers = rpcUsersList
        useTestClock true
        p2pAddress "localhost:10002"
        rpcSettings {
            address("0.0.0.0:10003")
            adminAddress("0.0.0.0:10004")
        }
    }
    new File('build/nodes').mkdir()
    new File('build/nodes/docker-compose.yml')
}
```

API gateway connecting to Party A:

```
FROM java:8
ADD build/libs/server-0.1.jar server-0.1.jar
ENV JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
ENTRYPOINT ["java", \
            "-jar", \
            "server-0.1.jar", \
            "--config.rpc.host=party-a", \
            "--config.rpc.port=10003", \
            "--config.rpc.username=user1", \
            "--config.rpc.password=test"]
```

Comment: Hi, I think the error: "O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB not in expected set [O=Notary, L=London, C=GB] {allowedRemoteLegalNames=O=Notary, L=London, C=GB, localCert=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, remoteAddress=localhost/127.0.0.1:10002, remoteCert=O=PartyA, L=London, C=GB, serverMode=false" is telling you that you're trying to connect to the Notary, but the the certificate provided from the receiver is for PartyA. How are you generating certificates for each of the nodes? Are you copying certificates around as part of the set up process? Are you sure 127.0.0.1:10002 is the P2P address for the Notary?

Comment: At the moment I just use deployNodes with DockerForm, I haven't generated any certificates yet. I will add more excerpts in regards of the setup

Comment: Yes, think that's it, as Chris mentioned below, now I understood. Will try it later. I connect back to party a instead of to the notary. Baby steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to replace the localhost part with the docket network's IP addresses:
https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#default-networks

Also make sure to expose the right ports on each container so that they can be accessed by the other containers:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

I suspect that the error you're getting is because PartyA is connecting to it's self, and not to the container that's running the notary node